# MAC Address as Serial Number in Embedded Systems

Tags: mac-address

Is it safe to use the MAC address as the serial number of a microcontroller in embedded systems? Is it a security threat or can it be duplicated perhaps? (Usually through software from what I read).

Comment: What security threat are you trying to mitigate? As it's currently written, you have not indicated what purpose the serial number is for, and why duplicates (or duplication) would be a security issue. What protocols does the embedded system communicate through? Is it an IOT device? etc.

Comment: Hi Patrick, unfortunately I worded the question in an incorrect manner. My main concern was whether the MAC Address can be similar between two different chips of the same manufacturer. When I contacted the manufacturer concerned he commented that from their end it is randomly generated and thus there might be a very slight chance of two MAC addresses being duplicate.

Comment: The [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) would suggest that the chance of duplicates is orders of magnitude higher than your proclaimed "0.000001%", but the exact value of course depends on the number of devices manufactured and how many of the 48 bits are actually seeded with randomness, and not just hardcoded to some predefined value for the manufacturer, the chip family, etc. If you're really just asking about whether they're unique, then the question is completely off-topic.

Comment: Again, apologies for having a non well informed question. Perhaps I should update with an appropriate question and answer. My percentage was merely an off hand figure just to give an example.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with a "non well informed question". There's two other problems though. One, your question is either off-topic or it doesn't have enough detail to write an answer that could qualify as "correct" without making several assumptions or adding personal opinion. Two, your answer at best does not cite any references to back up your claims, or at worst is providing factually incorrect information. And in any case, the answer contains no information of a nature that indicates the question is on-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm going to delete the question since it does not seem to be helping anyone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MAC Addresses are generated randomly by the manufacturer but as far as I understood there is a slight chance (0.000001% perhaps) that the MAC Address will be duplicate. i.e. it is not entirely unique.